# Accessing the same data repository in multiple viewmodels android architecture components

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have one data repository that is responsible for talking to my dao

I then have 2 viewmodels that get an instance on the repository but one ViewModel is always returning my live data object as null, the other works fine

Anyone have any idea to what could be happening, is it because the other ViewModel has a reference to the LiveData object first and only one is allowed?

Comment: can you post the code?